# error no match for operator<<

Tags: c++, object, vector, display

I am making this pizza program but I keep getting this error with the vector. it keeps saying "error: no match for operator<<"

this is my code

Pizza.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Order;
class Pizza
{

friend void display(Pizza,Order);
 private:
double price;
 char typeofPizza;
char sizeofPizza;
int toppings;
string pizzaType;
string pizzaSize;

 public:
 void setTypeOfPizza(char);
 string getTypeOfPizza();
 void setSizeOfPizza(char);
 string getSizeOfPizza();
 void setToppings(int);
 int getToppings();
 double calculate();
 void loopPizza(int);
 void displayPizza();
};

class Order
{

 private:
    vector <Pizza> customerOrder;
    string customerName;
    string customerNumber;
    //int pizzaOrderd=1;

public:
    void setName(string);
    string getName();
    void setNumber(string);
    string getNumber();
    void addPizza(Pizza);
    void displayOrder(Pizza);

};
```

Pizza.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pizza.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



void Pizza::setTypeOfPizza(char t)
{

typeofPizza=t;
switch(typeofPizza)
{
    case 'H': case 'h' :
    pizzaType="Hand Tossed";
    break;

    case 'D': case 'd':
    pizzaType="Deep Dish";
    break;

    case 'P': case 'p' :
    pizzaType="Pan";
    break;
    default:
        cout<<"Invalid size";
    }
}


string Pizza::getTypeOfPizza()
{
   return pizzaType;
}

void Pizza::setSizeOfPizza(char size)
{
sizeofPizza=size;
switch(sizeofPizza)
{
    case 'S':
    pizzaSize="Small";
    break;

    case 'M':
    pizzaSize="Medium";
    break;

    case 'L':
    pizzaSize="Large";
    break;
    default:
        cout<<"Invalid size";
    }
}

string Pizza::getSizeOfPizza()
{
   return pizzaSize;
}

void Pizza::setToppings(int t)
{
    toppings=t;
}
int Pizza::getToppings()
{
    return toppings;
}

void Order::setName(string n)
{
    customerName=n;
}
string Order::getName()
{
   return customerName;
}
void Order::setNumber(string num)
{
   customerNumber=num;
}
string Order::getNumber()
{
return customerNumber;
}

double Pizza::calculate()
 {
 if(sizeofPizza=='S' || sizeofPizza=='s')
   {
       price=10.00;
   }
 else if(sizeofPizza=='M' || sizeofPizza=='m')
   {
    price=14.00;
   }
 else if(sizeofPizza=='L' || sizeofPizza=='l')
   {
      price=17.00;
   }
   price+=(toppings *2);
    return price;
}

void Order::addPizza(Pizza p)
{
     customerOrder.push_back(p);
     p.displayPizza();

     cout<<"\n\n";
}

void Pizza::displayPizza()
{
     cout<<"\nPizza Type: "<<getTypeOfPizza();
     cout<<"\nPizza Size: "<<getSizeOfPizza();
     cout<<"\nNumber of Toppings: "<<getToppings();
     cout<<"\nPrice of Pizza: "<<calculate();
}

void Order::displayOrder(Pizza a)
{
   int n=0;
   cout<<"Name: "<<getName();
   cout<<"\nNumber: "<<getNumber();

for(unsigned int i=0,n=customerOrder.size(); i<n; i++)
        {
            customerOrder[i]=a.displayPizza();
            cout<<customerOrder[i]; 

        }

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pizza.h"
using namespace std;

void fillvector(vector<Pizza> &);
int main()
{

    char pizzaType;
    char pizzaSize;
    int toppings;
    Pizza a;
    Order b;
    string number;
    string name;
    char choice;
    cout<<"What is your name: ?\n";

    getline(cin,name);
    b.setName(name);

    cout<<"\n\nWhat is your phone number: ?\n";

    getline(cin,number);
    b.setNumber(number);


    cout<<"\n\nWhat type of pizza would you like?";
    cout<<"\n\n(H)and tossed\t\t(D)eep Dish\t\t(P)an: ";
    cin>>pizzaType;
    a.setTypeOfPizza(pizzaType);

    cout<<"\n\nSize of Pizza?";
    cout<<"\n\n(S)mall \t\t(M)edium \t\t(L)arge: ";
    cin>>pizzaSize;
    a.setSizeOfPizza(pizzaSize);

    cout<<"\n\nHow Many Toppings? ($2.00 a topping)";
    cin>>toppings;
    a.setToppings(toppings);



    cout<<"\n\nWould you like to add more pizzas?Y or N\n ";
    cin>>choice;



    b.addPizza(a);
    while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    {


    cout<<"\n\nWhat type of pizza would you like?";
    cout<<"\n\n(H)and tossed\t\t(D)eep Dish\t\t(P)an";
    cin>>pizzaType;
    a.setTypeOfPizza(pizzaType);

    cout<<"\n\nSize of Pizza?";
    cout<<"\n\n(S)mall \t\t(M)edium \t\t(L)arge";
    cin>>pizzaSize;
    a.setSizeOfPizza(pizzaSize);

    cout<<"\n\nHow Many Toppings? ($2.00 a topping)";
    cin>>toppings;
    a.setToppings(toppings);


    b.addPizza(a);
    cout<<"\n\nWould you like to add more pizzas?Y or N\n ";
    cin>>choice;
    }
    b.displayOrder(a);


}
```

I dont what I am doing wrong I am trying to add the displayPizza function to each spot in the vector. Unless I am not allowed to do that. could anyone please educate me.

Comment: Which line is your error occurring on?

Comment: on pizza.cpp at the end of the file where the for loop is where it says                      customerOrder[i]=a.displayPizza();

Comment: I'll suggest you attach the screenshot of the error messages/stack

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
cout << customerOrder[i];
```

`customerOrder[i]` returns a reference to `Pizza`, on which you attempt to call `operator<<`. Your class doesn't have it overloaded.

Either you print just some of its properties in-place:

```
cout << "type: " << customerOrder[i].getTypeOfPizza() << " size: " << customerOrder[i].getSizeOfPizza() << endl;
```

Or you implement the `operator<<` for future usage:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Pizza const& pizza)
{
    return os << pizza.getTypeOfPizza() << /* another attributes to print */;
}
```

Comment: could I do this in the for loop?

Comment: You mean `cout << "type: " ... `? Yes, that's inside `for` loop.